# C# Webrequest response is really slow when multithreading

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

So I have a program that will send many webrequests. It sends like this:

```
be.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(1).ForAll(Send);
```

this will send it and add it to the ThreadPool

```
private void Send(string emailName)
{
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        Console.Title =
            $"{emailName}{_domain} /::/ {_tries} /::/ {Sw.Elapsed.ToString("dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss")}";
        _tries++;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            var request =
                (HttpWebRequest)
                    WebRequest.Create("http://www.realmofthemadgod.com/account/forgotPassword?guid=" + emailName +
                                      _domain);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                if (reader.ReadToEnd() != "<Success/>") return;

                if (logToFile)
                {
                    lock (_syncRoot)
                    {
                        var reader1 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + _userPath + @"\Desktop\accounts.txt");
                        using (var writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\" + _userPath + @"\Desktop\accounts.txt")
                            )
                        {
                            if (!reader1.Contains(emailName + _domain))
                                writer.WriteLine(emailName + _domain);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Found: " + emailName + _domain);
                _synthesizer.Speak("New account found");
            }
        });
    }
```

and if the request returns 'Success/' it will basically tell me.

When I let it run it'll do the 700 requests in about 0.5 seconds but then it will take a few minutes to tell me the results.
I'm wondering how to make it so that when the request is sent it will tell me if it returned 'Success/' and not 5 minutes after.